# Multithreaded client in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, networking, python-3.6

I'm having a problem when I connect to the server, it connects properly and the code in the thread runs perfectly, the problem is that it appears as if I'm not receiving any message, or at least self.data is not updating, I tried checking with print("") and it appears as if the while loop after I start the thread is not reached by the code. Here is my code:

```
class Client:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def __init__(self, address):
        self.sock.connect((address, 10000))
        self.playerID = PID
        self.data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


        iThread = threading.Thread(target=self.game(self.data))
        iThread.daemon = True
        iThread.start()

        while True:
            data = self.sock.recv(2048)
            datas = pickle.loads(data)
            for i in range(0, len(self.data)):
                self.data[i]= datas[i]
            if not data:
                break

    def game(self, data):
        morecode...
```

Comment: Does `game` return anything?

Comment: Hi, no, it only sends messages to the server and updates a list

Comment: It seems you are calling `self.game(self.data)` when you create the `Thread`, rather than letting the thread call it.

Comment: How should I get the Thread to call my game function?

Comment: Have you looked around to see any examples of creating a thread with a target that has arguments?

Comment: Now that you mention that, no, I haven't, I will check that out, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an experiment where a `Thread` is given targets without arguments, but the target already closes over the arguments it needs:

```
from threading import Thread

import time

def func1(data):
    time.sleep(2)
    data.append(2)


def func(data):

    def func2():
        func1(data)

    print(data)
    t=Thread(target=func2)
    t.start()
    t.join()
    print(data)
    t=Thread(target=lambda: func1(data))
    t.start()
    t.join()
    print(data)


func([0])
```

Output:

```
[0]
[0, 2]
[0, 2, 2]
```

This answer is here to show that there are ways to give a `Thread` a target which is a form of closure.

Comment: I't alredy worked, thank you, I followed you're advice and checked how to use a thread with and argument, it apears the argument is a tupple so i had to specify the argument in that tuple, like this: iThread = threading.Thread(target=self.game, args=(self.data,))